# Making a grid of <video> elements in vue.js, with drag & drop ordering and resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

I've tried a few libraries and Vue.js plugins already, but after testing they all appeared to be lacking one/more of the necessary features.

I need to create a grid of video HTML elements, that can be dragged and dropped around to reorder them, and that can be resized with a consistent aspect ratio of 16:9

Also, i'm using typescript in vue.js

plugins/libraries I've tried:

- [jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout)
- [dattn/dnd-grid](https://github.com/dattn/dnd-grid)
- [mauricius/vue-draggable-resizable](https://github.com/mauricius/vue-draggable-resizable)

i've also tried just plain css grids, but coudn't get the drag & drop to work with the video elements

Does anybody have some advice/links that could help me?

First question btw :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML Drag and Drop interfaces work well but they require a lot of work.
The best drag & drop library I've seen is the one from Shopify; it's very slick!
[https://shopify.github.io/draggable/](https://shopify.github.io/draggable)